# Why are these XML tags creating an error in my PHP?

Tags: php, css, xml, svg

I am trying to use XML in a PHP document. I am getting an error for the `<?xml` and the `?>` tags. I assume PHP is trying to read the XML tags as PHP tags. Does anyone know what bug is?

```
<body>
     <?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="stylebox.css" ?> 
     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
         <rect id="p1" x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" />
         <rect id="p2" x="200" y="100" width="100" height="100" />
     </svg>
</body>
```

Comment: if there is no PHP on that page, you can display the PHP engine on that page using .htaccess (or on all the .xml files for that matter)

Comment: It's probably short tags being on that's causing that.  If possible, you should disable them.  If not, then one very ugly solution would be to echo that line out as a literal string in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is short php open tags creating problem. Change settings in you php.ini file

Put :

```
short_open_tag = Off
```

Otherwise assign this value in a variable in place of 
     `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="stylebox.css" ?>` :

```
$XMLstr='<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="stylebox.css" ?>';

echo $XMLstr;
```

Comment: Why bother with the variable?

Comment: Thanks Vasim - didn't realize there was a short_open_tag in my php.ini. All fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP is trying to parse your `<? ?>` tags as short opening and closing PHP tags.
Try printing this using `echo`, `print`, etc.:

```
<body>
     <?php echo '<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="stylebox.css" ?>'; ?>
     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
         <rect id="p1" x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" />
         <rect id="p2" x="200" y="100" width="100" height="100" />
     </svg>
</body>
```