# Stop VML being parsed as PHP

Tags: php, vml

With the introduction of IE8 the following 2 lines of code were required in the head of an html document for VML to work.

```
<?import namespace="v" implementation="#default#VML" ?>
<style> v\:shape { display:inline-block } </style>
```

I recently converted my pages to PHP. How do I stop the first line of code being parsed as PHP and the following error?

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_NAMESPACE

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are these XML tags creating an error in my PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634162/why-are-these-xml-tags-creating-an-error-in-my-php)

Comment: Couldn't you just slap that in an echo statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the php.ini config file to not allow short open tags

```
short_open_tag = Off
```

After this change only `<?php` will be interpreted as PHP, not `<?`

Comment: I think this can be done in .htaccess using `php_value short_open_tag 0` if you don't have access to php.ini

Comment: Thanks tomfumb and ian, I expect to be on a shared server so presumably I won't have access tp php.ini? However, the .htaccess solution works with testing on my localhost. Cheers.

Comment: @martin once you're on a production server I would hope that this php.ini setting would be off by default - this has been the recommended setting for several years. One reason to keep it on is to support legacy code, but in that scenario you might find each site has its own php.ini file